# Joomla 2.5 component: How to set directory for media field in admin form?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-component

I created a custom component, in the admin-form, I have a field to select a photo.

In `administrator/models/forms/example.xml` I can define that field:

```
<field name="photo" type="media"
    label="COM_EXAMPLE_FORM_LBL_PHOTO"
    description="COM_EXAMPLE_FORM_DESC_PHOTO" 
    filter="raw"
    directory="/images/example/photos" 
/>
```

**The Problem:**
When I push the select button, the media manager's directory is set to `/images`, though.

I tried `directory="JPATH_ROOT/images/example/photos"` --> same result.

How can I set `directory` so that media manager would open `/images/example/photos`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<field name="photo" type="media"
    label="COM_EXAMPLE_FORM_LBL_PHOTO"
    description="COM_EXAMPLE_FORM_DESC_PHOTO" 
    filter="raw"
    directory="example/photos" 
/>
```

Note: I have only used `example/photos`